# Facebook comments plugin for country specific?

Tags: facebook

I am new to Facebook API, gone through the diff blogs and Facebook developer and implemented Facebook comments plugin in my site.

I have a question that, do we need to add any thing specific to the country to show the content in their language or Facebook will take care of it?

Because my site is available in different countries like Brazil, Spain, and etc..

Thanks,
Ranjith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the different Facebook plugins use the local of the logged on user. You don't need to handle this yourself.